# Global timer JavaScript in KML

Tags: javascript, kml, html

I have a timer script which shows the time of system in Description tag

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
setInterval('tick()',50);   //tick is a plugin and 50 is in ms delay time
 function tick()
 {
   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=new Date();
 }
</script>
```

I want that if one placemark is placed in India , then same script should show the current time of India and if one placemark is in America , it should show America Time only regardless of machine in which KML has been loaded.

How can I do this (how can I sync all times)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude) at Stack Overflow, it should help you with your problem.

They discuss several services, where you can request the timezone/local time over a Lat/Long value.